# Asynchronous for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose

Ok, the following code works correctly for me, it is the usual way I do asynchronous loops (count is async). So before callbacking I get 3 numbers logged, in principle different.

```
var arrayIds = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var totalIds = arrayIds.length;
var done = 0;
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayIds.length; i++) {
    mongoose.Model.count({ 'likes.id': arrayIds[i] }, function (err, c) {
        count += c;
        console.log(c);
        if (++done < totalIds) return; //else
        callback(count);
    })
}
```

BUT I don't know what is happening in this other case, with the same philosophy, please help:

```
var arrayIds = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var totalIds = arrayIds.length;
var done = 0;
var likesPartial = [];
for (var m = 0; m < arrayIds.length; m++) {
    likesPartial.push(arrayIds[m]);
    profiles.count({ 'likes.id': { $in: likesPartial } }, function (err, u){
        console.log(u);
        if (++done < totalIds) return; //else
        callback(u);
    })
}
```

The problem is that I get the same 3 numbers logged (with the value of the expected last 'u', the one callbacked in the end), while they should in principle be different, because likesPartial array has at each step a different number of elements.

The two examples seem analogous to me, that's why I can't find the error.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont know mongoose, but `for` cannot be `async`. You can look into recursion for looping.

Comment: What do you **want** the second example to do?

Comment: rigorously speaking, I suppose you mean "for cannot have async functions inside". in that case, i say "no". example 1 works. I'm not sure this is the best way to do things, but they CAN be done that way

Comment: sheriff: @Rajesh is right that `for` loops cannot be asynchronous, but that doesn't mean they can't *start* a series of asynchronous operations. :-) Your use of a `for` above is just fine.

Comment: T.J. my code is simplified here. i just expect the second code to log 3 different numbers, and the same number is logged 3 times

Comment: @Rajesh what does "for loops cannot be asynchronous" simply mean?? i understand why for and async have to be dealed with correctly, but that's all

Comment: @sheriff `for loops cannot be asynchronous` means a `for` loop will not wait for response that has been called inside it. If you wish to add delay, best way is to use recursion. This way, you'll wait and when you receive response, initiate next iteration.

Comment: next time read the post and try to understand before saying the first thing that comes to your mind. i knew that and it must be clear from the way i posted the question

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you're updating `count` with each callback and when the last callback comes in, you're calling `callback` with the final result in `count`. Which makes sense.

Your second example is markedly different: It receives multiple values but **ignores** all but the last one (other than logging them), and then calls `callback` with just the last `u` it receives. So the previous `u`s it received are thrown away, which doesn't immediately seem to make sense (not least because you can't know which `u` it is, assuming the operation is asynchronous; they could complete in any order).

---

Another thing I noted is this:

```
profiles.count({ 'likes.id': { $in: likesPartial } }, function (err, u){
// ----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're passing in the **array** of `likesPartial` each time, whereas in your first code snippet, you're passing a single **ID** (`arrayIds[i]`), not an array.

Comment: Ok, they are not completely analogous. 2 values of u are not callbacked and lost IN THAT RESPECT.
But regarding, the logs, I should have 3 different logs IN THE SAME WAY as in the 1st example, shouldn't I?

Comment: @sheriff: Yes. That doesn't mean they can't happen to all have the same value.

Comment: @sheriff: You're also passing a markedly different parameter into the call, see update above.

Comment: the only thing i expect code 2 to do is log 3 different values. it does not

Comment: @sheriff: Did you see my note about what you're passing in, and how it's different from what you pass in in your first call? I can see a scenario where it ends up only ever returning the `u` value for the first entry in the array...

Comment: yes, the query is different, i m aware. the sense in which i say the 2 codes are analogous, is that the log is of the local variable (first c, then u) which should take a different value every loop, right?

Comment: @sheriff: As I said above: Right. But just because you're logging a different `u` on each callback, that doesn't necessarily mean that the value of those different `u` parameters aren't all the same. You'll need to do more debugging. The fundamental answer to your question is "Yes, you're logging different `u` parameters each time."

Comment: let me see if i understand. you mean that, in code 2, the 3 queries give the same result right? i thought so and did each of the 3 cases separately in mongo console. the answers are different...

Comment: @sheriff: I'm saying that the code correctly logs the `u` that was given to the callback. Either the code in the question isn't an accurate reflection of your real code (something was lost when you simplified it), or the callback is being called with the same value repeatedly.